# SMS Reply script gammu

Tags: bash, shell, raspberry-pi, sms, gammu

My very 1st post to ask for help.

The below script wishes to do:

Receive an SMS that if it has 50% to reply and post an event

Then verify the reply against the a range 1 -10 and if within range and from the same number to revert with message or else to revert with different one.

When it reverts with 2nd message to the number revert with a general message to all others.

What do you think?

```
#!/bin/sh
from=$SMS_1_NUMBER
message=$SMS_1_TEXT
gammu-smsd[939]: Process failed with exit status 111

if test "$message" = "50%"; then
    reply="BRAVO DWSTE TO NOUMERO TRAPEZIOU!"
    delay 1
    curl "http://10.18.214.12:9999/sendLocalEvent?eventName=event1"
    if test [ "$message" -ge 1 -a "$message" -le 10 ] && [ "$from" = "$from" ] ; then
     reply="-50% DIKO SAS"
     delay 1
     curl "http://10.18.214.12:9999/sendLocalEvent?eventName=event2&eventParam=e[ "$message" ]"
    else
       if [ "$from" = "$from" ]; then
          reply="TO NOUMERO TOY TRAPEZIOU EINAI LATHOS"
       else
          reply="O NHKHTHS VRETHIKE EYXARISTOYME"
       fi
       echo "$reply" | sudo gammu sendsms TEXT "$from"
     sendto="694"
     message=$SMS_1_TEXT
     from=$SMS_1_NUMBER
     echo "$from\n$message" | sudo gammu sendsms TEXT "$sendto"
    fi
    echo "$reply" | sudo gammu sendsms TEXT "$from"
elif test "$message" = "Ping"; then
    reply="Pong!"
else
    reply="PARAKALW PROSPATHISTE XANA"
fi
echo "$reply" | sudo gammu sendsms TEXT "$from"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not use gammu directly when using SMSD, send message through SMSD by using [gammu-smsd-inject](http://wammu.eu/docs/manual/smsd/inject.html).

If you have troubles debugging the script see http://wammu.eu/docs/manual/faq/smsd.html#the-runonreceive-script-fails-how-to-fix-that